# How do you debug Flutter in VsCode?

Tags: debugging, flutter, visual-studio-code

How does one debug their Flutter code while the app is running an in-app simulator?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you launch your Flutter project from VS Code with `F5`/`Debug -> Start Debugging` then normal debugging functionality (such as breakpoints, stepping, etc.) should *just work* (and hot-reload will automatically fire on-save).

Comment: I am getting an error after pressing F5 in the debug console: error handling 'checkPlatformOverride' custom request: _flutter.listViews: (-32601) Unknown method "_flutter.listViews".
Error handling 'checkBrightnessOverride' custom request: _flutter.listViews: (-32601) Unknown method "_flutter.listViews".
Error handling 'serviceExtension' custom request: _flutter.listViews: (-32601) Unknown method "_flutter.listViews".
Error handling 'checkIsWidgetCreationTracked' custom request: _flutter.listViews: (-32601) Unknown method "_flutter.listViews".

Comment: @GoldenLion please file an issue at https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code

Comment: I am loading visual studio code and flutter on my win 10 box and trying it there.